# Android - Parse deviceToken different from deviceToken in .getInstallationId();

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging, devicetoken

I want to save the **deviceToken** I have in *Parse* to a **User** in my ***database*** with my
Rest Api.

However when I try to get the **deviceToken** within my ***Android code***
it looks like this:

*0d0082b0-2ba7-41de-835b-3e01v8d5c6ae*

But in the Parse.com -> Core it looks like this:

*APA91bFncivC9Q5sOvIiv-MUTtIjrHnrq0S5MIS_Zfd6SWGR0p2O--Ih2AAJI7THsEXqiPyRHnYjSlZ9foc81fOksmzuAKfVznJ6m1kBFmMxE5otxS58KT7WuOO6UZ2qg_IYp_cwIt_2*

To retrive the deviceToken in android I use this code:

```
String deviceToken = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getInstallationId();
```

that returns *0d0082b0-2ba7-41de-835b-3e01v8d5c6ae*

Answer (score 2):

Installation ids are not the same as device tokens. In order to get the device token, you have to use:

```
String deviceToken = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getString("deviceToken");
```